# Extra space added after link tag in html email

Tags: html, html-email

This regards HTML emails...

For some reason email-clients are adding an extra space after a text link.

Here's the code:

```
<a href="http://foo.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; color:#249A10;">foo</a>
```

So clients will display this as 'foo '

Any ideas where this extra space comes from?

Comment: tried removing whitespace between `</a>` and following tag? http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol7/html_no1.htm

Comment: Can you show the original 1:1 code that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` for your a tag.

Answer (score 0):

It won't show the white space in its current form. If you have wrapped your `a` tag within `td` or `span`, you may have missed something there. I mean the container of `a` tag, otherwise it should just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

add a whitespace nowrap fixed the issue for me.

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="https://www.example.com/" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12px;line-height: 16px;color: #221e1f;text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer;">https://www.example.com/</a>.</span>
```

Hope this helps to fix the 10+ years old issue